# how to get the valuse from different select ( drop down lists)?

Tags: html, jsp, jquery, jsp-tags

Its very important to me, i want to know how to get values from different selects having different options for them.

example code :

```
  <select name="select1" >
    <option> helo</option>
    <option>hai</option>
 </select>

  <select name="select2" >
    <option>thanks alot</option>

 </select>
```

Comment: really what are you looking for? what is the problem you are facing now while trying to get values from two different selects??

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[name="select1"]').val();
```

and

```
$('[name="select2"]').val();
```

will get the selected values for your current markup using jQuery.  It will not change when the values change, it will only be what they are at the time you call that code.

If you need to update the values every time they change, you can bind to the `change` event, like this:

```
$('[name="select1"]').on('change', function(){
    select1_change = $(this).val();

    //logging the changed value for demo
    console.log('select1 has changed to: ', select1_change);
});
```

See [this JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xguX/) for the example, check the console to see the values update.

Answer (score 0):

From technologies you tagged in your question, i understood that you need to get the values from dropdown and send it via jquery ajax to servlet. Why don't you consider about adding id to your dropdowns? Like this in html,

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option> helo</option>
    <option>hai</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2">
    <option>thanks alot</option>
</select>
```

And in your javascript,

```
function updateValues(){
   var value1 = $("#select1").val();
   var value2 = $("#select2").val();
   $.ajax({
        url: "ur_servlet_url&value1="+value1+"&value2="+value2,              
        type: "POST", 
        success: function(data){
             //If you want to return anything in jsp.
    } 
   });
}
```

Hope this helps you.